# Is there a definitive modding community for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm looking to download some mods for Minecraft. I'm new to the modding community and unsure whether there is a website or community centered around modding Minecraft that is a 'One-stop' place for most Minecraft mods, similar to other communities for other games.

Does such a community exist? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: I doubt you'll find a place that lists every single mod, ever.  Regardless, we're not a website recommendation service, I'm afraid.

Comment: @fbueckert This is a fairly common problem when getting started with mods for minecraft, and fortunately, the modding community is highly organised, so a canonical "right" answer is possible.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie But still, off topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's a website recommendation.  There *is* no right answer, no matter how organized anyone is.

Comment: @fbueckert A highly-organised community, by definition, has a centre. That centre allows for canonical answers that can stand on their objective centrality.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Except that recommendations, *by definition*, are subjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most official list of mods you can get is maintained on the [Minecraft forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/) in the [Mods subforum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/51-minecraft-mods/), in [the first pinned topic](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1434593-list-of-mods-for-162-last-updated-july252013/). The nice thing about using the forums is that you're going directly to the source – these forums are where the mod developers release their mods, so you're always sure to have the most up-to-date version publicly available directly from the author.

Currently, that pinned topic is:

- [List of Mods for 1.6.2 (Last Updated: July/25/2013)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1434593-list-of-mods-for-162-last-updated-july252013/)

... but the pinned topic's content and title is always updated to cover the latest Minecraft version, so don't let the very specific title worry you that it will become obsolete.

That thread's first post also has a link to an off-forums page where you can browse a sortable list of mods by various criteria such as which version of Minecraft it's compatible with, Forge compatibility, and so on, as a convenience for forum members and for easy updating by the list maintainers. The list is crowdsourced by fans from the release threads scattered around the forums as well as mods released off the forums, so it's extensive and rather high quality.

Comment: I just want to add that although there are high quality lists, such as the one mentioned above, there will likely never be one definitive list.  If for no other reason, many modders have strong personalities, and when you get that many strong personalities in one place, there will always be disagreements that causes someone to start their own place to put mods.

Answer (score -1):

There's a downloadable program you can get, called *Curse Client*. It lists most mods, maps, and seeds that the community has to offer.

Comment: Curse does not list every mod, map or seed, only ones which have been allowed by their authors. There are many excellent mods not available via Curse